# Creating a FakeRequest in play

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to setup a FakeRequest. According to the docs here:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.test.FakeRequest$

it is part of play.api.test

However in my Ide, and at compile it is not recognized. Here is the code:

```
import play.api.test._

object QuickCheck {

   val fakeRequest = new play.api.test.FakeRequest()   <--- ERROR!

}
```

Note, I am doing this from within a regular package in the src directory tree, not in the test tree. Even in the test tree it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code (or API docs), you'll see that the FakeRequest class doesn't have a no-argument constructor - https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Fakes.scala

However, the companion object has an "apply" factory method that takes no-arguments. So you can do things like this (note: calling an Object() is the same as calling Object.apply()):

```
val request = FakeRequest()
val request2 = FakeRequest().withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/json")
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not actually recognize the FakeRequest as being anywhere in the play.api.test._ package as the docs suggest. It is as if the docs are wrong and the Class/Object is not actually part of the play.api.test package.

Comment: It definitely is: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Fakes.scala#L30